# Fabric.js + Google Fonts

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts, fabricjs

Is that possible to use [Fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/How-to-render-text) with web fonts, without attaching Cufon library and its fonts? I can easily do it with standard canvas functionality so I wonder if it's possible in Fabric.

Comment: The native text rendering is now implemented, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're [planning to ditch Cufon](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Roadmap%2C-TODO) soon, in favor of native text methods. We incorporated Cufon ~2 years back when native text methods weren't very cross-browser available (see [this test of mine](http://kangax.github.com/jstests/canvas_fillText_test/) from back in the days). Once we drop it, it will probably be an optional module, for cases when compatibility in older clients is important.

Answer (score 7):

First link the google font in the `<head>`

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Lobster|Fontdiner+Swanky|Crafty+Girls|Pacifico|Satisfy|Gloria+Hallelujah|Bangers|Audiowide|Sacramento' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Create a div/span

```
<span class="txtFont" style="font-family:Oswald" onclick="change_font_family('Oswald')">Oswald</span>
```

In Javascript

```
function change_font_family(font_family)
{
   canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", font_family);
   canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: It work on the form but when we export canvas.toSVG(), fonts are not loading in svg. Any help?

Comment: This works but can you please how to load the italics of the font and apply them as well

Comment: @AamirNakhwa Yep you can simple do that by adding your used fonts appended to the svg file 
`<style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" type="text/css">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Charmonman&display=swap');
</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    .........
</svg> `

Comment: thanks for your reply when I have to open that svg into illustrator, and external links didn't work with it...

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem just this time.

You have to **load the font in dom before** you can use it in canvas with fabric.

So you can create an element, wich has the style attribute with the font you want.

For some my solotion may be interesting. I create a select where the user can select the font. In this select each  get the attribute font-family.

Look at this:
[image]

*Why a new answer? Because the key in the store is the font, which was not mentioned directly.*

Comment: These fonts are not working when we export canvas into svg by canvas.toSVG(). Any help with it?